# how to calculate zonal temperature gradient?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I want to calculate the zonal temperature gradient. My data is 3D array `(780,5,45)` and want to gradient along longitude. I used the function as `dTm_dx = np.gradient(Tm,dx)[2]`, `dx` is 2D array `(5,45)`. The error is :

```
1709 dx[i] = diffx
1710 else:
-> 1711 raise TypeError("invalid number of arguments")
1712 
1713 edge_order = kwargs.pop('edge_order', 1)
```

> TypeError: invalid number of arguments

How can I solve my problem? Thanks

Comment: Please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also read the documentation: you need to pass the `axis` keyword to `np.gradient` to give the differentiation axis, rather than indexing into the resulting 3d array.